# Passing value from input to SVG attributes via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Below are my codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <svg width="12cm" height="12cm" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <line x1="20" y1="20" x2="20" y2="300" stroke="red"/>
    <line x1="20" y1="300" x2="300" y2="300" stroke="red"/>
    <rect id="bar1" x="40" y="280" width="30" height="20"/>
    <rect id="bar2" x="100" y="260" width="30" height="40"/>
    <rect id="bar3" x="160" y="180" width="30" height="120"/>
    <rect id="bar4" x="220" y="240" width="30" height="60"/>
    </svg>

    <br>
    <input id="input">
    <input id="button1" type="button" value="Set Value" onclick="setHeight()"/>
    <script>
       function setHeight(){
        var value1 = document.getElementById("input").getAttribute("value");
        var value2 = parseFloat(value1);
        document.write(value2);
        document.getElementById("bar2").setAttribute("height", value2);
       }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to pass the value of **"input"** into the **"height"** of **"bar2"**.
But something is wrong in the script that the **"input"** is not converted to int value.

Thanks

Comment: use document.getElementById("input").value instead of the attrib method, which only sees hard-coded value attribs, not current form input values. the equivalent dom property is defaultValue, not value. also, don't use document.write(), use console.log or document.title (on mobile) for that sort of debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting `input` value like this

```
var value1 = document.getElementById("input").value;
```

and setting it to `bar2` like this

```
document.getElementById("bar2").style.height = value2 + 'px';
```

Comment: Thanks! the .value helped!